# place contacts into black list from my iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have needed to place contacts into blacklist.

Does anyone knows how can i place contacts in blacklist from my iphone ??

Any Private APIs ???

Thanks in Advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no public API for this in the SDK, AFAIK.

For phone call ringing, you can create an entry in your Contacts directory, add your blacklisted numbers to this entry, and set the ringtone for this entry to a silent one (which can be found in the web, and loaded onto your phone via iTunes).

For SMS and true phone call blacklisting you may need to subscribe to this service from your cellular phone provider.

For email blacklisting, again, you may need to do this on your email provider's side.

Comment: Thanks good one. But i can't implement it,because it's alternative  way to solve my problem.